Print specific sheets with quantities from cells in contents page
I am still very new to this and trying to find a way to print specific sheets from my file with quantities entered on main sheet  when clicking on specific cell (c21).  To summarise I have a main sheet that lists sheets with the sheet name in column b - these have links that direct to sheets when clicking on cells.  Sheets are deactivated when clicking away from them.  On the main sheer there is a corresponding column with quantities required for printing (column d).  This changes depending on how many of each sheet are required at the time of printing.  I want the code to print each sheet (column b) from the contents page with the quantities entered in column d, ignoring any zeros.
This is the code I have entered - it is probably quite long and OTT! It is currently not picking up the quantities from the main sheet so I am obviously doing something wrong!
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c21")) Is Nothing Then

        Sheets("Health & Safety File 1").Visible = True
        Sheets("Sign In Sheets").Visible = True
        Sheets("Induction Forms").Visible = True
        Sheets("Visitors Induction Forms").Visible = True
        Sheets("Induction Presentation").Visible = True
        Sheets("Toolbox Talk Confirmation").Visible = True
        
        Sheets("Sign In Sheets").PrintOut copies:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Health & Safety File 1").Range("d8").Value, collate:=True
        Sheets("Induction Forms").PrintOut copies:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Health & Safety File 1").Range("d10").Value, collate:=True
        Sheets("Visitors Induction Forms").PrintOut copies:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Health & Safety File 1").Range("d12").Value, collate:=True
        Sheets("Induction Presentation").PrintOut copies:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Health & Safety File 1").Range("d14").Value, collate:=True
        Sheets("Toolbox Talk Confirmation").PrintOut copies:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Health & Safety File 1").Range("d18").Value, collate:=True
        
        Sheets("Sign In Sheets").Visible = False
        Sheets("Induction Forms").Visible = False
        Sheets("Visitors Induction Forms").Visible = False
        Sheets("Induction Presentation").Visible = False
        Sheets("Toolbox Talk Confirmation").Visible = False
        
    End If
End If


In which module you placed this code? What is the Sub exact name?

Are you sure you are even going into that code? Have you used the debugger to check you have your hard-coded ranges correct?
Instead of relying on selecting a specific cell I would place a button on the sheet. Then you could do something like this
Sub demo_Click()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Health & Safety File 1").Range("B2:D30")
    'Change the range above to suit your actual scenario
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = rng.Value
    'If you examine arr in the watch window, observe that it is now a base 1, 3D array

    'Work your way through the array doing what you need to do...
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To UBound(arr)
        'The sheet names are in arr(x, 1)
        If Len(arr(x, 1)) > 0 Then
            'Make the sheet visible (why?)
            Sheets(arr(x, 1)).Visible = True
            
            'The copies required are in arr(x,3)
            Dim NoCopies As Integer
            NoCopies = arr(x, 3)
        
            If NoCopies > 0 Then
                Sheets(arr(x, 1)).PrintOut copies:=NoCopies, Collate:=True
            End If
        
            'Make the sheets invisible
            Sheets(arr(x, 1)).Visible = False
        
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Look to the comments in my code to see what is going on or see this video from Paul Kelly Excel Macro Mastery
EDIT: Some methods to try to avoid the caching of the Number of copies (see comments)
'Try re-initialising the Printer e.g.
If NoCopies > 0 Then
    'Reinitialise the printer
    Application.ActivePrinter = Application.ActivePrinter
    Sheets(arr(x, 1)).PrintOut copies:=NoCopies, Collate:=True
End If

.
.
.
'Alternatively use PageSetup each time
If NoCopies > 0 Then
    'Reset the page
    PageReset Sheets(arr(x, 1))
    Sheets(arr(x, 1)).PrintOut Copies:=NoCopies, Collate:=True
End If

.
.
.
Private Sub PageReset(shtName As String)
    With Sheets(shtName)
        .PrintArea = "" 'might want to make this explicit
        .FitToPagesWide = False
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Copies = 1
    End With
End Sub


Thank you so much for coming back to me.  I think I understand the logic behind this, and it should work better than my original stab, however it is still not performing :( It appears to dislike the line arr=rng.value (could this be because there are zeros in my data for sheets not to be printed?)  I may have to come back to this later this evening with a clearer head - I hope!

No - I had zeroes in my test data. By "dislike" what do you mean - is there an error message? Is arr still not populated?

Thank you so much for your help - it is much appreciated!  I have moved the data into a table and tested the coding again and it works in printing all of the specified sheets, however it is not picking up the correct quantities.  It is printing the same quantities as the coding I originally entered which is weird.  I have checked the formatting of the cells and these are definitely stored as numbers.  Is there anything else I could be doing wrong that you can think of ?

It appears to be overriding the quantities with the last printed settings for each sheet and printing those quantities instead - is there any way to override this?

Ah - looks like the Printer settings are being cached. You could try resetting the printer in the loop with Application.ActivePrinter = Application.ActivePrinter. I'll update my solution with another option (not enough characters in comments)

Thank you!  I just tried resetting the printer with the code you suggested, unfortunately this did not work.  I will try the page resets this afternoon.  Do I need to insert the second part of the code on each sheet to be printed?

No, it just needs to be in the same module as demo_Click(). In hindsight I should have probably made it Public instead of Private
